# Traducir datos que lleguen de una API con ngx-translate

Tags: angular, api

Buen día, estoy utilizando ngx-translate a mi proyecto y va de maravilla, todo muy bien. El único detalle que tengo que aún no encuentro como resolver traducir los datos consumidos de una API.

Este es un ejemplo de como viene la respuesta de la API que estoy consumiendo:

```
{
    email: "correo@email.com"
    descripcion: "Esta es la descripcion que quiero traducir"
    id: 1
    telefono: "9988776655"
    updated_at: "2020-08-03 01:13:52"
}
```

En específico, necesito traducir la propiedad `descripcion` pero no se muy bien como realizar esa parte. Las demás traducciones que tengo aplicado en mi proyecto, están en ficheros `es.json` y `en.json` respectivamente.

Mi pregunta es, si es posible realizar traducciones a propiedades que vengan de una API, o necesariamente tiene que estar definido en los archivos de traducción `.json`

Comment: Hay dos soluciones. 1a: que la api devuelva la traducción. 2a que la api devuelva un key en la descripción que esté en los ficheros de traducción y usar el pipe `translate` para que se haga la traducción.

Comment: @hawks El detalle es que los datos de la API van a estar variando, es decir, tengo un dashboard en donde el usuario puede estar modificando esa parte de `informacion`; si el usuario lo necesita, puede cambiar los valores de `informacion`, por lo tanto no puedo tener valores estáticos en los archivos de traducción, sería algo dinámico.

Comment: pues creo que la solución es que lo devuelva la api ya traducido. Puedes enviar un header a la api del idioma seleccionada y el server devuelva la traducción en función del header.